# Finding integrating factor by $z=xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a differential equation $Mdx+Ndy=0$ Show that

$(\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}})/(Ny-Mx)$ is a function of $g(z)$ here $z=xy$

then integrating factor is $\mu=e^{\int{g(z)dz}}$

Here what i know only is integrating factor can be found $\mu=e^{\int{\frac{\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}}{N}}}$ But I do not know where to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that there is an integrating factor of the form $\mu(xy)$. Then multiplying through by $\mu$ should make the equation $\mu M \; dx +\mu N \; dy =0$ exact.  So we must have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu M) = \mu M_y+x\mu 'M = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu N)=y\mu 'N+\mu N_x.$$

Solve for $\mu'$ to get:

$$\mu'(z) =(\mu M_y-\mu N_x)/(yN-Mx) = \mu (z)\frac{M_y-N_x}{Ny-Mx}.$$

If this last fraction (your $g$) is a function of $xy$, then such a $\mu (xy)$ exists and you can solve the separable differential equation for $\mu$:

$$\frac{\mu'}{\mu } = \frac{M_y-N_x}{Ny-Mx}=g(z)$$

$$\ln(\mu ) = \int g(z) \; dz$$

$$\mu = e^{\int g(z) \; dz}$$.

Just be sure to put everything in terms of $z$.

Note, the integrating factor you put in your question is for the case when $g$ is a function of $y$ alone. $\mu(x)$, $\mu (y)$ and $\mu (xy)$ are different cases and each has it's own formula.

Comment: Why do we have x right here? $x\mu 'M$

Comment: it is in your first equation.

Comment: Well, $\mu$ is a function of $z$, but we have to take the derivative with respect to $y$.  So $(d/dy)(\mu) = (d\mu/dz)(dz/dy)=\mu' x$.  The $x$ is the $dz/dy$.

Comment: I don't understand...In the 3rd line, how could you write $\mu^{'}$ for the differentiation of $\mu$ with respect to $y$ and its differentiation with respect to $x$. shouldn't it be $\mu_{x}$ and $\mu_{y}$?

Comment: Here, $\mu'$ is with respect to $z = xy$.

Comment: Oops...didn't read your last comment well enough. thanks.